# Flutter cannot find Git

Tags: flutter, windows, git, dart, installation

I installed successfully Flutter on Windows with Android SDK and Visual Studio Code.
Because I don't have enough space in my **C:**, I decided to move Flutter and Android SDK in my **D:**.

Since then, Flutter is unable to find git when I run `flutter doctor` or other flutter command : `Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.`.

My PATH variable contains well Git and Flutter : `[...];C:\Windows\system32;D:\Programs\flutter\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\bin`.

When I move back flutter on my **C:**, everything works well.
I tries to unistall/reinstall Git, delete/redownload flutter, reboot, remove flutter/dart files on %APPDATA%... Nothing better.

Does anyone have a solution ?

Comment: I specify that I correctly followed the documentation and recommendation on other StackOverflow questions.

Comment: perhaps reboot your computer can solve this error

Comment: Did you run `flutter doctor` in cmd or git-bash? What about `where git` or `which git`?

Comment: @Zhentao I already rebooted without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s no problem with moving the flutter projects to your D, however the program itself has to remain to stay in C, otherwise you will have some extension issues later similar to one that you just have.

So I suggest you to move your flutter program files back to C, and in order to save some spaces I suggest you to move your projects file to D